# HC-06 bluetooth with FPGA

Tags: verilog, fpga, intel-fpga

I have to use the `HC-06 bluetooth module` (the one usually used for `arduino` projects) with a `de0-nano altera fpga kit`.

I really have no idea how to go about it. Am I suposed to treat the `HC-06` as a simple serial port and just implement the `UART` communication? I have to develop a verilog design for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the communication with HC-06 and the FPGA must happen over a UART interface. so, go ahead and write some logic to implement UART on FPGA so the communication can take place. In the process of doing so, a lot of things will get clear for you.

Comment: Thank you, i just implemented the UART interface using a 9600 baud, paired it with my smartphone using a bluetooth terminal app and was able to send data from the FPGA to the smartphone.

Answer (score -1):

Does this look like doYourHomeWork.com? lol I would start [here](http://www.tec.reutlingen-university.de/uploads/media/DatenblattHC-05_BT-Modul.pdf).
They have some examples of connecting hc's to different systems, and it's only 16 pages with loads of pictures.

edit: Additionally [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/AT-command-mode-of-HC-05-Bluetooth-module/?ALLSTEPS) provides some great information about working with your hc chip in the context of arduino. As far as how things are done (enter at mode etc...) It explains nicely.